Problem with camera rolling instead of orbiting in camera controller
I have this basic orbit camera controller set up. The pitch works perfectly fine, but I am failing to properly get the Yaw to orbit around the object horizontally (like a model viewer or blender orbit camera). It appears to just Roll in place, instead of Yaw. I have tried multiple implementations, but none actually stop the camera from rolling. Thank you for any assistance.
use cgmath::{Matrix4, Point3, Vector3, InnerSpace, EuclideanSpace, Rad, Angle, MetricSpace};

pub struct Camera {
    pub position: Point3<f32>,
    pub target: Point3<f32>,
    pub up: Vector3<f32>,
    pub fov: f32,
    pub aspect_ratio: f32,
    pub near: f32,
    pub far: f32,
    pub yaw: f32,
    pub pitch: f32,
}

impl Camera {
    pub fn new(position: Point3<f32>, target: Point3<f32>, up: Vector3<f32>, aspect_ratio: f32) -> Self {
        Self {
            position,
            target,
            up,
            fov: 45.0,
            aspect_ratio,
            near: 0.1,
            far: 100.0,
            yaw: -90.0,
            pitch: 0.0,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_view_matrix(&self) -> Matrix4<f32> {
        Matrix4::look_at_rh(self.position, self.target, self.up)
    }

    pub fn get_projection_matrix(&self) -> Matrix4<f32> {
        cgmath::perspective(cgmath::Deg(self.fov), self.aspect_ratio, self.near, self.far)
    }

    pub fn rotate(&mut self, delta_yaw: f32, delta_pitch: f32) {
        self.yaw += delta_yaw;
        self.pitch += delta_pitch;

        if self.pitch > 89.0 {
            self.pitch = 89.0;
        } else if self.pitch < -89.0 {
            self.pitch = -89.0;
        }

        let yaw_rad = Rad(self.yaw.to_radians());
        let pitch_rad = Rad(self.pitch.to_radians());

        let x = yaw_rad.cos() * pitch_rad.cos();
        let y = pitch_rad.sin();
        let z = yaw_rad.sin() * pitch_rad.cos();

        let front = Vector3::new(x, y, z).normalize();
        self.position = Point3::origin() - front * self.position.distance(Point3::origin());

        self.target = Point3::origin();
        self.up = Vector3::unit_y();
    }

    pub fn zoom(&mut self, delta: f32) {
        let direction = (self.target - self.position).normalize();
        self.position += direction * delta;
    }
}

The snippet called for main.rs would be. But I believe the issue lies within the camera.rs code above.
let mut last_frame_time = Instant::now();
    let mut frame_times = vec![];
    let mut width = 800.0;
    let mut height = 600.0;

    let mut camera = Camera::new(
        Point3::new(0.0, 0.0, 3.0),
        Point3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        Vector3::new(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        width / height,
    );

    let mut is_rotating = false;
    let mut last_mouse_position = (0.0, 0.0);

    el.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        *control_flow = ControlFlow::Poll;

        match event {
            Event::LoopDestroyed => return,
            Event::MainEventsCleared => {
                windowed_context.window().request_redraw();
            },
            Event::RedrawRequested(_) => {
                let current_frame_time = Instant::now();
                let delta_time = current_frame_time.duration_since(last_frame_time).as_secs_f32();
                last_frame_time = current_frame_time;

                frame_times.push(delta_time);
                if frame_times.len() > 100 {
                    frame_times.remove(0);
                }

                let fps = if !frame_times.is_empty() {
                    1.0 / (frame_times.iter().sum::<f32>() / frame_times.len() as f32)
                } else {
                     0.0
                };

                println!("FPS: {:.2}", fps);
                println!("Model count: {}", models.len());

                let view = camera.get_view_matrix();
                let projection = camera.get_projection_matrix();

                unsafe {
                    gl::Viewport(0, 0, width as GLsizei, height as GLsizei);
                    gl::ClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
                    gl::Clear(gl::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl::DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                    gl::Enable(gl::DEPTH_TEST);
                }

                renderer.render(&models, &view, &projection);

                windowed_context.swap_buffers().unwrap();
            },
            Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } => match event {
                WindowEvent::CloseRequested => *control_flow = ControlFlow::Exit,
                WindowEvent::Resized(physical_size) => {
                    windowed_context.resize(physical_size);
                    width = physical_size.width as f32;
                    height = physical_size.height as f32;
                    camera.aspect_ratio = width / height;
                },
                WindowEvent::MouseInput { state, button, .. } => {
                    if button == MouseButton::Middle {
                        is_rotating = state == ElementState::Pressed;
                    }
                },
                WindowEvent::MouseWheel { delta, .. } => {
                    let zoom_amount = match delta {
                        MouseScrollDelta::LineDelta(_, y) => y * 0.5,
                        MouseScrollDelta::PixelDelta(pos) => pos.y as f32 * 0.05,
                    };
                    camera.zoom(zoom_amount);
                },
                WindowEvent::CursorMoved { position, .. } => {
                    let (x, y) = (position.x as f32, position.y as f32);
                    if is_rotating {
                        let delta_x = x - last_mouse_position.0;
                        let delta_y = y - last_mouse_position.1;
                        camera.rotate(delta_x * 0.1, delta_y * 0.1);
                    }
                    last_mouse_position = (x, y);
                },
                _ => (),
            },
            _ => (),
        }
    });
}

